# Auto remember on DropDownList fields using Session.

Tags: asp.net, session

I want to implement "auto remember" feature of a form. This app is used by accountants who track cheque payments.

The accountant is entering a number of checks at a time and it will be time saving to maintain the project, beneficiary and project instead of choosing them every time you want to add a transaction.

The form looks like attached.[image]

So far my attempts are failing and i keep seeing the dash entry '-' always at the top of each of the three dropdownfields as if i did nothing. 
However 'watch' paramters shows that the Session values are properly retrieved and set. 
I'm trying to save the previously entered values of those fields in a Session. Unless someone has another thought. 
The nature of the fields in the asp file is as such

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddAccount" runat="server" Height="24px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddAccount_SelectedIndexChanged" >
        <asp:ListItem>-</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    *<br />
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddProject" runat="server" Height="22px" >
        <asp:ListItem>-</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    *<br />
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddBenificiary" runat="server" >
        <asp:ListItem>-</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    *<br />
    <br />
```

On Page_load I added the following Session getters and setters. I choose to populate first, i.e get the accounts, projects
etc then set the proper value based on the sessions.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            user = (User)Session["user"];

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Session["IsValidUser"] == null || Session["IsValidUser"].ToString() != "true")
                    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx", false);

                /// Setting the Body tag. 
                Site1 m = (Site1)Master;
                m.PageSection = "transactions";


                //////////////////////////
                Populate();

                if (Session["BankAccount_ATx"] == null)
                {
                    Session.Add("BankAccount_ATx", null);                                                
                }
                else ddAccount.DataTextField = Session["BankAccount_ATx"].ToString();

                if (Session["Project_ATx"] == null)
                {
                    Session.Add("Project_ATx", null);                                                
                }
                else   ddProject.DataTextField = Session["Project_ATx"].ToString();

                if (Session["BenefClient_ATx"] == null)
                    Session.Add("BenefClient_ATx", null); 
                else
                    ddBenificiary.DataTextField = Session["BenefClient_ATx"].ToString(); 
            }               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
    }
```

I save the chosen value in the session on the save button.

```
    Session["BankAccount_ATx"] = ddAccount.SelectedValue;

    Session["Project_ATx"] = ddProject.SelectedValue;

    Session["BenefClient_ATx"] = ddBenificiary.SelectedValue;
```

Many thanks guys and gals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store your value using:

```
Me.Session.Item("LastDdlValue") = Me.YourDdlValue.SelectedValue
```

You can use this code in `Page_Load` event when `Not Me.Page.IsPostBack`:

```
If Not IsNothing(Me.Session.Item("LastDdlValue")) Then
    Me.YourDdlValue.SelectedValue = Me.Session.Item("LastDdlValue")
End If
```

Please note that you need to populate your `DropDownList` before setting its `.SelectedValue`.

Comment: this is what i ended up using

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the selected value of the dropdownlist, like this:

```
if (Session["Project_ATx"] == null)
{
    Session.Add("Project_ATx", null);                                                
}
else {
    // Find the list item in the drop down that mataches the value in your session 
    ListItem li = ddProject.Items.FindByValue(Session["Project_ATx"]);

    //Check to see if the list item was found in the drop down
    //If it's found, then make it the selected item 
    if ( li != null )
        li.Selected = true;

}
```

If you were storing the Text value in Session then use this method instead:
    **FindByText**

Comment: What do i do with the boolean li.Selected? Please elaborate.  And how does this statement sets the dropDownlist value:   ListItem li = ddProject.Items.FindByValue(Session["Project_ATx"]);?

Comment: I've added some comments.

Comment: my prelim testing is working. Thanks for the solution.  I used FindByValue since i was retrieving and storing them by value and not by their corresponding text.  How does li.Selected sets the value. I'm still lost :)!?   Shouldn't be something like `ddProject.SelectedValue = Session["Project_Atx"].toString()`   instead?

Comment: Actually doing simply this works.  `ddAccount.SelectedValue = Session["BankAccount_ATx"].ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

FindByText is the best method, alternatively you can iterate through the items in the dropdown using for loop compare each item with the value saved in session. If they are equal set selected index

```
     for(int i=0;i<dropdownlist1.Items.count;i++)
     {
       if(dropdownlist1.Items[i].Text==Session["Project_ATx"].ToString())//use dropdownlist1.Items[i].Value if you have stored the dropdownlist item value instead of text 
       {
         dropdownlist1.SelectedIndex=i;
         break;
       }
     }
```